# How to create union type in Typescript based on another type?

Tags: typescript

I have this type

```
type ListingFilterBy = {
  season?: string[];
  name?: string;
  isOnMarket?: boolean;
};
```

And I want to create a union type based on the `ListingFilterBy` type that would look like this:

```
type FilterAction =
  | { key: "season"; value: string[] }
  | { key: "name"; value: string }
  | { key: "isOnMarket"; value: boolean };
```

Is there a way to create a type so that the TS compiler knows that the `key` field in `FilterAction` type is a key of the `ListingFilterBy` type?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
type ListingFilterBy = {
  season?: string[];
  name?: string;
  isOnMarket?: boolean;
};

type FilterActionMap = {
  season: string[];
  name: string;
  isOnMarket: boolean;
};

type Unionize<T> =  Exclude<{
  [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof T
    ? { key: K, value: T[K] }
    : never;
}[keyof T], undefined>;

type UnionizedFilterAction = Unionize<ListingFilterBy>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Map over each key of `ListingFilterBy`, removing `undefined`:

```
type FilterAction = {
  [K in keyof ListingFilterBy]-?: { key: K ; value: Exclude<ListingFilterBy[K], undefined> };
}[keyof ListingFilterBy];
```

then, use `keyof ListingFilterBy` to get the final union.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2HAdgcwGJwDbAgJwCEQoBeKAbwCgooEIBDBAexQH4AuO4fVNAbQC6AbhpQUDALYRO3XulG1EAeRQBZBvgDWEYLIBGzZtkYpRAX1FVQkKFlwEAggGNkrMpTH8A0lFRQdEGYAM1hEZHR7PCIQQQBaWQoAiBAuX2EoADcGbABXCC4AUQAPZzyAEwgAHngkPiiCYh9BABooXJRK4NQIcoA+KEsqc35AkLC6yJxo4hEqKgB6BagbaAb8FzcUMkXl2gAfSmTUqAAieiZWU4zsvIK5PiFB3dooQ6TArlOJaWusnPyXCQ8jQzyWr3exy+KnUmh0wD+t0BUEMxlMg2EQA)

---

You may also use `NonNullable<ListingFilterBy[K]>` if you want to remove `null` as well.